# upload images in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I'm trying to uploads images but this error exception exist 
[image]
and i wrote  this code  for validation

```
 `$this->validate($request,['title'=>'required|unique:home,title|max:20',
        'image'=>'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,gif|max:2048|']);`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uncomment this line in php.ini into php folder.

extension=php_fileinfo.dll

and restart the server(enter 'php artisan serve' again)